# How to tell if /dev/ttyX is Textbased?

Tags: linux, framebuffer, tty

i want to find all text-based ttys. How can i tell that a tty is not running a graphical system like X? I didnt find any ioctl doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between X-based ttys ans normal pseudo ttys. They are the same.
What you can find, if it is a virtual console (/dev/tty*) or a pseudo terminal (/dev/pts/*).
In this case you have different major numbers of the devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for console ttys, usually, there is a getty or similar program running in this tty.

```
ps -ef | grep getty
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly what ive searched for.